# file_exists() loop doesn't detect when file is added to directory

Tags: php, while-loop, file-exists

I currently have a script that loops for 30 seconds. Essentially, I'm looking to set up a temporary 'watch folder' that fires a command when the file exists. When I run this PHP, it doesn't detect the file when I successfully change the file name (via FTP) of `video_renders/something.mp4` to `video_renders/video.mp4` within the 30 seconds that the script is running.

Here's my PHP:

```
<?php

$endtime = time() + 30;

while (time() < $endtime ) {

$filename = "video_renders/video.mp4";

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    //do something
     echo "Success";
 }

}

?>
```

Is there something I'm missing here? Why doesn't my looping PHP script pickup files that are added to the `/video_renders` directory?

Thank you!

Comment: You're trying a relative path, you need an absolute one - `if( file_exists( getcwd() . $filename ) ) { ....`

Comment: That doesn't seem to help. But thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This would be a better approach:

```
while( !file_exists($pathToFile) )
{
    sleep(1);
}
```

It will put your script to sleep each second and then check for the file. You can change it to make it run only for 30 times.

Comment: Just tried-- still no luck. One thing I've noticed, not only does the script not pick up on the filename change, but I need to completely reload the browser to test the script again (with the existing filename). Seems like a caching issue for sure, but `clearstatcache()` doesn't seem to be doing the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, PHP doesn't cache information about non-existent files. 
So, if you call `file_exists()` on a file that doesn't exist, it will return `FALSE` until you create the file. If you create the file, it will return `TRUE` even if you then delete the file. However `unlink()` clears the cache automatically.